# Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6.6: SSLSessionCache shm set, file never written?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

My site runs on CentOS 6.6 and Apache 2.2 over HTTPS. I'm trying to use [SSLSessionCache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache) to speed things up.

This is my config:

```
SSLMutex file:/var/log/httpd/SSLMutex
SSLSessionCache shm:/var/log/httpd/SSLSessionCache(16184)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600
```

The webserver was restarted without errors.

Problem: I'm not sure that is working.

In `/var/log/httpd/` I see neither files (I also tried to touch+chmod them manually, but then `[error] (17)File exists: Cannot create SSLMutex with file /var/log/httpd/SSLMutex'` so I deleted them).

What can I check?

Comment: Have you ever got this resolved? I'm facing the same problem, exactly CentOS 6 with 2.2, there is no files under the directory. Although, is your syntax correct for SSLSessionCache? Isn't it supposed to be `shmcb`? Something like `SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)`

Comment: Not resolved still waiting for ideas